# Make multiple directories based on a list

Tags: python

Hi 
I would like to make multiple new dir's in a set root dir each one named based on a list of names

e.g.

List looks like this

Folder_1

Folder_x

Folder_y

is there an easy way to do this in python?

Answer (score 18):

```
import os

root_path = '/whatever/your/root/path/is/'
folders = ['Folder_1','Folder_x','Folder_y']
for folder in folders:
    os.mkdir(os.path.join(root_path,folder))
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way to do it using a flexible custom function. Note that it uses [os.makedirs()](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.makedirs) instead of [os.mkdir()](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.mkdir) which means that it will also create the root folder if necessary, as well as allowing the subfolder paths to contain intermediate-level directories if desired.

The code also uses [functools.partial()](http://docs.python.org/library/functools.html#functools.partial) to create a temporary local function named `concat_path()` to use with the built-in [map()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#map) function to concatenate the root directory's name with each subfolder's. It then uses `os.makedirs()` on each of those to create the subfolder path.

```
import os
from functools import partial

def makefolders(root_dir, subfolders):
    concat_path = partial(os.path.join, root_dir)
    for subfolder in map(concat_path, subfolders):
        os.makedirs(subfolder, exist_ok=True)  # Python 3.2+

if __name__=='__main__':
    root_dir = '/path/to/root/folder'
    subfolders = ('Numbers/Folder_1', 'Letters/Folder_x', 'Letters/Folder_y')
    makefolders(root_dir, subfolders)
```

Comment: The partial function seems an unnecessary complication.

Comment: @blokeley: With respect to its second use perhaps (so I've removed that), but the `lambda` alternative for `concat_path()` would be something like `for subfolder in map(lambda subfolder: os.path.join(root_dir, subfolder), subfolders):` so I feel the added "complexity" is worth it.

Answer (score 2):

Make folder name as desired

```
import os

root_path = '/home/sagnik'

folders= [None] * 201
for x in range(0,201):
    print(str(x))
    folders[x] ="folder"+str(x)
```

Create folders

```
for folder in folders:
    os.mkdir(os.path.join(root_path,folder))
```

Comment: `folders = ["folder_{}".format(x) for x in range(201)]`

Comment: @GinoMempin 201was just an example

Answer (score 1):

```
os.mkdir(name_of_dir)
```

is your friend.

Answer (score 1):

[os.path.join](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) to combine your root dir and name, and [os.mkdir](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.mkdir) to create the directories. Looping over things is easily enough done with for.

Answer (score 1):

```
import os

root_dir = 'root_path\\whateverYouWant\\'
list_ = ['Folder_1', 'Folder_x', 'Folder_y']
for folder in list_:
    os.makedirs(root_dir + folder)
```

Comment: This is the less safe, less portable version of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5728013/2745495). It's better to just use os.path.join than manually concatenating paths.

Answer (score 0):

I was in the same situation too and finally got a small working output, try it.

I had two files, first the program file and second a .txt file containing the list of folder names.

```
import os
f = open('folder.txt', 'r')
for g in f:
    os.mkdir(g)
f.close()
```

Comment: Hello Dinesh, and welcome to SO. Your question formatting is odd. I've edited to make it more readable. Try to put some effort in your formatting, it is largely appreciated by the community

Answer (score 0):

```
import os

dir_names = ["ABC1", "ABC2", "ABC3"]
#Create three folders on Desktop
#dir_path = os.path.expanduser("~/Desktop")
dir_path = os.path.join(os.path.join(os.environ['USERPROFILE']), 'Desktop')

for folder in dir_names:
    try:
        if not os.mkdir(os.path.join(dir_path,folder)):
            print(folder)

    except:

            print("Folder already exists")
            break
```

Answer (score -2):

```
from os import makedirs
makedirs('1/2/3/4/5/6/7/8/4/4/5/5/5/5/5/5/5/55/5/5/5/5')
```

By this, you'll more than you want.

Comment: This creates the directories as sub-directories of each other, instead of *root/Folder_1*, *root/Folder_2*, *root/Folder_3*, etc. which is, I think, what the OP wanted.

Comment: I am also looking just one line code and don't use lambda