# How can i make multipe directories in specific place in directory tree using os.makedirs?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wanted to make program that automaticly makes multiple directories inside previously created directory for photos of my drawings. Can i make program that create them with one line of code using function os.makedirs.

I have tried doing something like this:

```
os.makedirs(name + "/facebook, instagram)
```

But i know it's just terrible and as i was expecting it not to work.
This is my code:

```
os.mkdir(name)
os.mkdir(name + "/facebook")
os.mkdir(name + "/instagram")
```

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725679/make-multiple-directories-based-on-a-list/5728013#5728013).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do this in one line as follows:

```
import os
[os.mkdir(os.path.join("dir_location", d)) for d in ["dir1", "dir2", "dir3", "dir4"]]
```